# Make a destructive reverse! function in scheme

Tags: list, scheme, reverse

I need to create a program that will reverse a list destructively. For example lets say..

```
scm> (define L (list 1 2 3 4))
scm> (reverse! L)
(4 3 2 1)
scm> L
(1)
```

Where L becomes the last element of the reversed list. I know I am supposed to use set-cdr! somehow but cannot figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this looks like homework, I can't give you a straight answer. I'll show you the general structure of the solution, so you can figure out the details and fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (reverse! lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (acc '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (let ((tail <?1?>))
          (set-cdr! <?2?> <?3?>)
          (loop tail lst)))))

(define lst (list 1 2 3 4))
lst
> (1 2 3 4)

(reverse! lst)
> (4 3 2 1)

lst
> (1)
```

In the above code:

- The original list is traversed using a named `let` for simplicity, given that another parameter is needed
- A new `acc` parameter is defined, to serve as the accumulator for the reversed list
- When the recursion ends, the answer in the accumulator is returned

Now, for the recursive step:

- In `<?1?>` we need to obtain a reference to the rest of the list and save it, given that we're going to modify it
- The key point lies in the line `(set-cdr! <?2?> <?3?>)`. You'll have to set the *next* element of the current list to the previously accumulated, reversed list
- Finally, the recursion proceeds with the new accumulated values

Notice that in the end, the `lst` reference got modified in-place and now is pointing to the last element of the list. If you need `lst` to point to the reversed list, then simply do this:

```
(define lst (list 1 2 3 4))
lst
> (1 2 3 4)

(set! lst (reverse! lst))
lst
> (4 3 2 1)
```

The procedure described reverses a list destructively and doesn't create a new list (no `cons` operations are used.)

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [section on mutators](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/start.html#./start%3ah9) from the [The Scheme
Programming Language](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/) book.  Also, look into the the `case` function in Scheme. Essentially, you can use the `set!` function to fundamentally change a definition and also give another output.

Answer (score 0):

How de fella UCB.

here is my solution for your HilAcke.

```
(define (reverse! L)
     (define (helper prev cur)
           (if (null? cur)
               prev
               (let ((next (cdr cur)))
                   (set-cdr! cur prev)
                   (helper cur next))))
     (helper '() L))
```

then after defined you can check with the usual

```
 (define L (list 1 2 3 4))
 (define LR (reverse! L))
 LR
 > (4 3 2 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was wondering how to do this today since I needed it for a test. For every list with more than 1 element I keep the first `cons` in the argument as the first in the result. I make a fresh cons to hold the new last value with a dummy value, then I reverse the link for elements 2..n-1. In the end i set the car of the first `cons` and the new `last`. The result is the result of the last `set-cdr!`.

```scm
(define (reverse! lst)
  (if (or (null? lst)
          (null? (cdr lst)))
      'soup ; an undefined value. You may use something else
      (let ((last (list 1)))
        (let loop ((prev last) (cur (cdr lst)))
          (let ((next (cdr cur)))
            (if (pair? next)
                (begin
                  (set-cdr! cur prev)
                  (loop cur next))
                (begin
                  (set-car! last (car lst))
                  (set-car! lst (car cur))
                  (set-cdr! lst prev))))))))
```

Example:

```
(define test '(() (2) (3 4) (5 6 7) (8 9 10 11 12 13 14 16)))
(for-each reverse! test)
test ; ==> (() (2) (4 3) (7 6 5) (16 14 13 12 11 10 9 8))
```