# How to make a destructive filter! in scheme?

Tags: filter, scheme, reverse

I can get the filter works, but it does not do it destructively. Below are the starting code and test cases:

```
(define (filter! f s)
;;Your solution
```

Test cases:

```
(define (big x) (> x 5))

(define ints (list 1 10 3 8 4 7)) 
(define ints1 (cdr ints))


(define filtered-ints (filter! big ints))  
filtered-ints 
; expect (10 8 7) 

(eq? filtered-ints ints1) ; expect #t
```

Could anyone help please?

Comment: You mean that the filter will change the list given as argument by removing the elements that do not pass the test? What's the use of `ints1` here?

Comment: I'm not sure either, but I guess it is something related to the pointer being changed in the original input list that makes filtered-ints and ints1 equivalent. That is what confusing me the most.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a destructive reverse! function in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266086/make-a-destructive-reverse-function-in-scheme)

Comment: @matt `reverse!` is quite different from `filter!`, this is not a duplicate question

Comment: @ÓscarLópez - oh yeah. Mea culpa. They both popped up together and I was too quick on the close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(define (filter! f lst)
  (let loop ((ans lst))
    (cond ((null? ans)
           ans)
          ((not (f (car ans)))
           (loop (cdr ans)))
          (else
           (scan-in f ans (cdr ans))
           ans))))

(define (scan-in f prev lst)
  (if (pair? lst)
    (if (f (car lst))
        (scan-in  f lst  (cdr lst))
        (scan-out f prev (cdr lst)))))

(define (scan-out f prev lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst))
    (if (pair? lst)
        (if (f (car lst))
            (begin (set-cdr! prev lst)
                   (scan-in  f lst (cdr lst)))
            (loop (cdr lst)))
        (set-cdr! prev lst))))
```

I adapted the above from the [`filter!`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#filter!) procedure in SRFI 1: List Library. Notice that if you're using Racket a thing or two needs to be modified for the above code to work properly. For example, Racket no longer supports `set-cdr!` and you'll have to use `set-mcdr!` instead.